# Proximity sensor on when hand move around Sensor

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, proximity

I am developing one app in that i want to get the proximity sensor on when user move hand around proximity sensor and get proximity state value like 0. when user move hand second time value get 1 how may i do this i know how to enable proximity but i want to enable proximity when user move hand around proxy. so how may i do this i tried this code. to enable proximity.

```
UIDevice * device=[UIDevice currentDevice];
    device.proximityMonitoringEnabled=YES;

    if (device.proximityMonitoringEnabled)
    {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(handleProximityChange:)
                                                     name:UIDeviceProximityStateDidChangeNotification
                                         object:nil];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Device not capable to support Proximity sensor");
        // device not capable
    }
```

and catch the proximity state in this method...

```
-(void)handleProximityChange:(NSNotification *)notification
{

    NSLog(@"Proximity event catch");

}
```

i will do this code as per user hnd over in proximit so hoe may i do this please help me to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    count = 0;
    condition = 0;
    [self addProximitySensorControl];
}

-(void)addProximitySensorControl {

    UIDevice *device = [UIDevice currentDevice];
    device.proximityMonitoringEnabled = YES;

    BOOL state = device.proximityState;
    if(state)
    {
        NSLog(@"YES");
        _sensorSupport.text = @"YES";
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"NO");
     _sensorSupport.text = @"No";
    }

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(proximityChanged:)
                                                 name:@"UIDeviceProximityStateDidChangeNotification"
                                               object:nil];
}
-(void)proximityChanged:(NSString*)str
{
    NSLog(@"i am in proximityChanged");
    condition++;
    if (condition % 2 == 0) {
        count++;
    }
    _counter.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",count];
}
```

Comment: when 1st time move hand around proximity then proximity value get is on. and i neet to set counter 1.

Comment: @Ashwinkumar While answers with only code might answer the question, it is often useful to have at least a small introduction what you have changed, and why.